# Alpha Beta Pruning Optimization

Tags: java, tree, ai

I made a class that would do alpha beta pruning on a binary tree of 40 degree. However there is a time limit on a single move of 30 seconds. I am to play against my professor and his opponent class. I tried going down 6 levels but I would lose. I tried going down 7 levels and I was taking too long. Is there a way to make my code run faster? If possible can you also check my logic for the alpha beta pruning part and see if I missed anything causing it to run longer than it should. I will include all classes but I only need help with the Player class since that is the only one I'm working on. Everything else is given by the professor. I want it to run faster so I can go deeper down the tree so I have an advantage and win the game. The game is won if I end up with a positive number.

Player:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

    private Tree t;

    public Player(Tree t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    // play will take in the moves and the player (in this case the maximizer)
    // and return the best possible move
    public boolean play(ArrayList<Boolean> moves, boolean maxNode) {
        float alpha = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        float beta = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        // a will be the two possible moves that this node can take
        ArrayList<Boolean> a = (ArrayList<Boolean>) moves.clone();
        a.add(true);
        int level = 0; // Level is how far down it would go

        if (moves.size() < 14) {
            level = 19 - moves.size();
        } else if (moves.size() >= 14 && moves.size() < 34) {
            level = 6;
        } else if (moves.size() >= 34) {
            level = 39 - moves.size();
        }
        //System.out.println(moves.size() + "     " + level);
        alpha = Math.max(alpha, prun(level, a, maxNode, alpha, beta));
        a.remove(a.size() - 1);
        float al;
        al = alpha;
        alpha = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        a.add(false);
        alpha = Math.max(alpha, prun(level, a, maxNode, alpha, beta));
        if (al > alpha) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // prun is a recursive function that will determine alpha and beta
    public float prun(int level, ArrayList<Boolean> m, boolean maxNode, float a, float b) {
        if (level <= 0) {
            return t.value(m);
        }
        level--;
        ArrayList<Boolean> moves = (ArrayList<Boolean>) m.clone();
        ArrayList<Boolean> moves1 = (ArrayList<Boolean>) m.clone();
        // Child is all possible moves for a node.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> child = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>();
        child.add(moves);
        child.add(moves1);
        child.get(0).add(true);
        child.get(1).add(false);
        float score;
        for (ArrayList c : child) {
            score = prun(level, c, !maxNode, a, b);
            if (maxNode) {
                if (score > a) {
                    a = score;
                }
            } else if (!maxNode) {
                if (score < b) {
                    b = score;
                }
            }
            if (a >= b) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (maxNode) {
            return a;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Tree:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tree {
    public final int TOTALNODES=2097152;
    public final float EPSILON=0.00001f;
    public final float distribution=10.0f;

    public long randomSeed=0L;
    public float[] topTree=new float[TOTALNODES];
    private Random r=new Random();
    public long height=40;

    public Tree(long rs) {
        randomSeed=rs;
        r.setSeed(randomSeed);
        topTree[0]=topTree[1]=0.0f;
        int current=2; int levelNodes=2; float factor=1.0f;
        while (current<TOTALNODES) {
            for (int i=0; i<levelNodes; i++) {
                int parent=current/2;
                float sign=0.0f;
                if (r.nextBoolean()&&r.nextBoolean())
                    if (topTree[parent]>EPSILON) sign=1.0f; else sign=-1.0f;
                else if (topTree[parent]>EPSILON) sign=-1.0f; else sign=1.0f;
                float offset=((Math.abs(topTree[parent])<EPSILON)?(r.nextFloat()*2.0f*distribution-distribution):(r.nextFloat()*distribution*factor*sign));
                topTree[current]=topTree[parent]+offset;
                current++; }
            levelNodes*=2; factor*=0.9f; }
    }

    public float value(ArrayList<Boolean> moves) {
        // low and high will both be values between 0 and 2^21-1=TOTALNODES.
        // The depth will be the number of bits examined, starting with the low order bit of the low int.
        // A depth of 0 will indicate the root.
        int position=1;
        for (int i=0; i<Math.min(20, moves.size()); i++) {
            if (moves.get(i).booleanValue()) position=position*2+1; else position*=2; }
        if (moves.size()<=20) return topTree[position];
        r.setSeed(randomSeed+position);

        float[] bottomTree=new float[TOTALNODES];
        bottomTree[0]=bottomTree[1]=topTree[position];
        int current=2; int levelNodes=2; float factor=0.12157665459056928801f;
        while (current<TOTALNODES) {
            for (int i=0; i<levelNodes; i++) {
                int parent=current/2;
                float sign=0.0f;
                if (r.nextBoolean()&&r.nextBoolean())
                    if (bottomTree[parent]>EPSILON) sign=1.0f; else sign=-1.0f;
                else if (bottomTree[parent]>EPSILON) sign=-1.0f; else sign=1.0f;
                float offset=((Math.abs(bottomTree[parent])<EPSILON)?(r.nextFloat()*2.0f*distribution-distribution):(r.nextFloat()*distribution*factor*sign));
                bottomTree[current]=bottomTree[parent]+offset;
                current++; }
            levelNodes*=2; factor*=0.9f; }

        position=1;
        for (int i=20; i<moves.size(); i++) {
            if (moves.get(i).booleanValue()) position=position*2+1; else position*=2; }
        return bottomTree[position];
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long randomSeed=564715140;

        Tree t=new Tree(randomSeed);
        ArrayList<Boolean> moves=new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        Player player=new Player(t);
        Opponent other=new Opponent(t);
        int turn=0;
        for (int i=0; i<t.height; i++) {
            long before=System.currentTimeMillis();
            boolean maxNode=(turn==0);
            Boolean newMove=((maxNode)?player.play(moves, maxNode):other.play(moves, maxNode));
            if (newMove==null) throw new RuntimeException("No decision made.");
            moves.add(newMove);
            long after=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((after-before)>30000) {
                if (maxNode) System.out.println("The maximizer took too long: "+(after-before));
                else System.out.println("The minimizer took too long: "+(after-before));
                System.exit(0); }
            System.out.println("Time: "+(after-before));
            turn=1-turn;
        }
        System.out.println("Final score: "+t.value(moves));
    }

}
```

Opponent: (This would be the professor's class which I don't have so I just have it return random)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Opponent {
    private Tree t;

    public Opponent(Tree t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    // play will take in the moves and the player (in this case the maximizer)
    // and return the best possible move
    public boolean play(ArrayList<Boolean> moves, boolean maxNode) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        return (rand%2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Cloning vs copy-constructors

```
ArrayList<Boolean> moves = (ArrayList<Boolean>) m.clone();
```

[Instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java) `clone()`-ing, you should be using the constructor [`ArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) to create new `List` instances backed by the same elements as the original. This is safe for adding or removing elements on the newly created instances.

#### Interfaces over implementations

Interface types such as `List` is recommended over the implementing types, i.e. `ArrayList`, because the users of the variable should only need to use the methods provided by the `List` API without having to understand the underlying implementation. This is also known as loose coupling. Additionally, since Java 7, you can use [generic type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) to save you some keystrokes:

```
List<AVeryLongType> list = new ArrayList<>();
// instead of
// ArrayList<AVeryLongType> list = new ArrayList<AVeryLongType>();

// instead of ArrayList<T>
public static void methodName(List<T> list) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Boolean comparison and ternary conditions

In your `Player` class:

```
public boolean play(ArrayList<Boolean> moves, boolean maxNode) {
    // ...
    if (al > alpha) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public float prun(int level, ArrayList<Boolean> m, boolean maxNode, float a, float b) {
    // ...
    if (maxNode) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

You can also consider using the direct boolean comparison and ternary operators to simplify the expressions here:

```
public boolean play(List<Boolean> moves, boolean maxNode) {
    // ...
    return al > alpha;
}

public float prun(int level, List<Boolean> m, boolean maxNode, float a, float b) {
    // ...
    return maxNode ? a : b;
}
```

#### Code formatting styles

Your `Player` class's code formatting is the conventional kind, which a seasoned Java developer should be able to understand easily, and that is weirdly different from your `Tree` and `Main` classes. You should either make the `Player` class 'look' more like the rest for consistency, or make the code formatting of the other two more conventional.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! As mentioned above the `Main` and `Tree` are given by the professor so I have no control over them.

Comment: Can you also check the logic for the pruning part? I keep on losing to the professor and I'm not sure if it's because of my logic. Thank you!